# I want to change the string of text

Tags: react-native

This is my Text tag in react native i want to change its input value which is "abc" to "123" or any other string with the help of refs. edit()
        {
        this.refs.ref1
        }

```
<Text ref="ref1" onPress={this.edit.bind(this)}>abc</Text>
```

What is can use in edit function to change string in Text

Answer (score 1):

You can put the text in the state and update the state onPress, which will trigger react to update the ui:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {mytext:'abc'}
}

edit() {
  this.setState({mytext:'123'})
}

render() {
   return <Text ref="ref1" onPress={this.edit.bind(this)}>{this.state.mytext}</Text>
}
```

If you need to use a reference, then put a reference on the component that renders your Text and call `this.ref1.setState({mytext:'something'})` to dynamically change the text.